# Center-aligning a link

Tags: html, css, alignment

In the Category page, I need to center align the link to "Continue reading...". I've tried several methods and none of them are working.

This is the HTML on the page:

```html
<a class="more-link">Continue reading <span class="screen-reader-text">description</span> <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a>
```

I've tried the following CSS codes and none of them work:

```css
.more-link {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.more-link {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.more-link {
    text-align: center;
}
```

What is the proper CSS code to center-align the link?

Comment: You have given more-link class to which element?

Comment: Your html codes are not clear Tara

Comment: That's not HTML, and it's not even matched tags. Something is seriously amiss in your HTML code. Try [edit]ing to fix that; HTML that is properly indented will show up in the preview as code, rather than being rendered in the post.

Comment: I'm new here and I tried to copy over the HTML code directly and it does not show up in the post. I just swapped brackets for "<".

Comment: I did not write the code, I'm attempting to edit it. What precedes the more-link class is <a href="http://example.com"

Comment: I've fixed your HTML brackets. Also added a leading `<a` which I assume you'd left off. You should verify the HTML is representative of what you are using, and edit yourself if it is not.

Comment: @TaraBriscoe it is already align center. https://jsfiddle.net/wrz1e2k4/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the link in a div and apply `text-align: center` to the div, or set the div's align attribute to "center".

Samples:
[Link 1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_div_align_css) 
[Link 2](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_div_align)

Answer (score 0):

Directly *after* "Continue reading", there is a `[/span]` missing. This might already help.

However, that's a `<span>` tag, which is an "inline element", meaning it will go with the regular text flow.

If you want to center something, first of all it has to be in a block-element, like a `<div>`tag. With your setting `display: block;` you did turn it into a block element, but still this could be problematic, since the whole thing is probably inside another inline-element, like `<p>`. So to be able to center it, the least you have to do is to put it in a separate block element (p or div), independent from any other text.

Comment: Yes, it is a <p> element, but I don't want the entire paragraph centered (it contains the excerpt), just the link. So wrap the entire link in a <div> tag within the <p>?

Comment: Where would I add the <div> tag? This is for the Category page in WordPress. I used inspector to find the code, but I can't find the HTML in the Category.php file.

Comment: add the div _below_ (= after) the p tag

Comment: I found the file where the HTML originates, in another PHP file where elements are linked to the Category.php file. For someone that's new to PHP and CSS, this is causing my head to explode. I wrapped the HTML in a <div> tag and first assigned an id, then used CSS to text-align: center, and it did not center. Then I wrapped it in an inline <div> tag and wrote <div align="center"> and it still doesn't center. This is a <div> within another <div> but shows on inspector that it's within a <p> which is in the Category.php file. I don't know if that is affecting this at all, but nothing has worked.